# OBSOLETE - Stackwise: a beautiful way to browse Stack Exchange sites

Tags: app, obsolete

> ## Obsolete:  App not available, nor maintained for years. Source code not available.

## Stackwise: a new Stack Exchange browser for iOS devices.

[image]

### **New features**

- (v1.3) **Now with full iOS 7.0 support!** Also, check out tag subscriptions: create virtual topics based on Stack Overflow or Stack Exchange tags.
- (v1.2) Now you can scroll through images embedded in questions and answers with standard pan gestures. See all the details on image-heavy Stack Exchanges like [Photo.SE](http://photo.stackexchange.com)!
- (v1.1.1) Now with Instapaper support. You can **tweet** questions, **email** them or **post them to Instapaper**.

### About

A few months ago, I caught the Stack Exchange bug. I loved the depth of the communities, the depth of the questions, and the depth of the answers.

Where else could you find out the [pH feasible region for spherification](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/12717/use-of-algin-and-calcium-chloride-in-spherification), or indeed, [Who Framed Roger Rabbit?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/3324/who-framed-roger-rabbit)

But I wanted an iOS app which could give me a *bird's eye view* of my favourite Stack Exchange sites, and beautifully.

I wanted to see all my favourite sites, and scroll effortlessly through dozens of questions.

So when I couldn't find an SE app for iOS which met my needs, I decided to make one.

### Licence

Stackwise is a free app for iPhone, and a paid Universal app (iPad and iPhone).

### Download

On the iTunes App Store in two delicious flavours:

- [*Stackwise*](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/stackwise-stack-overflow-stack/id556308691?ls=1&mt=8): browse Stack Exchange in glorious HD, on both iPhone and iPad.
- [*Stackwise for iPhone* **(FREE!)**](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/stackwise-for-iphone-stack/id556299075?ls=1&mt=8): same great taste, for the iPhone. Try it and see!

### Platform

Stackwise is made for iOS devices capable of running iOS 5.0 and greater.

We've also updated it for iOS 6 and the new iPhone 5's 4-inch Retina display.

### Contact

Tweet me at [@OverpunchApps](http://twitter.com/OverpunchApps), or drop me a comment right here: I'm active on Stack Exchange after all. Bug reports, feature requests, cat videos: these have my attention.

### Code

Stackwise is built from battle-tested iOS frameworks like [Core Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/core-data), [RestKit](http://www.restkit.org) and [DTCoreText](http://cocoanetics.github.com/DTCoreText/).

## About Stackwise

### All 180+ Stack Exchange sites, now at your fingertips

Every site on the Stack Exchange network, at your service. **Long-press a site tile** to make it a favourite.
If you hang out on Meta sites, **long press the Stackwise title** on the sites screen to enter Meta mode.

### I'll take that as a comment

Access your Stack Exchange inbox wherever you are.

[image]

### A bird's eye view of your favourite Stack Exchange site.

Scroll through your favourite Stack Exchange site. When you get to the end, scroll some more with infinite scrolling. **Tap and hold** the site title to get more info about your favourite site. **Tap the magnifying glass** to search on tags or keywords.

[image]

### "Reputation does(n't) matter"

We all know rep shouldn't be taken too seriously. But we like keeping an eye on it all the same. Once you've logged in, **tap your user image** on the main sites screen to check your rep.
[image]

### Answers to life's questions

Stackwise is not responsible for the summoning of the [Dark Lord Zalgo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

Open answers in **Google Chrome, Safari**, or **view them right in Stackwise's inbuilt browser**.

[image]

**Tweet or e-mail** Stack Exchange questions, or **post to Instapaper!** (NEW).

[image]

### Give it a try!

Now on the App Store.

- [Get *Stackwise*](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/stackwise-stack-overflow-stack/id556308691?ls=1&mt=8)
- [Get *Stackwise for iPhone*](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/stackwise-for-iphone-stack/id556299075?ls=1&mt=8)

Comment: Could you please add the mathjax support on the Mathematics site? It is just a matter of adding a js file, but without this it is nearly impossible to read math. Thanks.

Comment: Also the displaying format is not fully correct. For example, codes are displayed in a weird font and not color. The app could get more polished to make people more willing to pay.

Comment: @dentisDark: Thanks for your comments. I agree that the Mathematics SE in particular is pretty hard to use unless you can compile TeX in your head. I'll be looking into supporting MathJax on the Mathematics SE, although we're using native iOS text rendering, so it unfortunately isn't as straightforward as including a JS file.

Comment: The Facebook login seems to not do anything. I can't login.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. We'll be looking at this and will get back to you.

Comment: It looks like your app is no longer available. If so, could you please mark your post as obsolete, by tagging and editing the title and body like [this](https://stackapps.com/posts/316/revisions)?